# It displays that one of my variables is not defined when from what i can see it is

Tags: python

This is the error which comes up:

```
What type of device is it?phone
What make of phone is it? [Iphone, Samsung or other]samsung
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Chris\School\School\computing\task 3 testing.py", line 79, in <module>
    if ('4') in model_iphone:
NameError: name 'model_iphone' is not defined
```

I have no idea how to fix it. It would be helpful if someone could point out some potential problems with my code. I know its not the most efficient code but it would be great to have some help with it thanks.

My code:

```
apple_question = []


for row in apple_file:
    apple_question.append(row)


other = open("task 3 other questions.csv")
other_file = csv.reader(other)

other_question = []

for row in other_file:
    other_question.append(row)

pre_questions = open("task 3 pre questions.csv")
pre_questions_file = csv.reader(pre_questions)

pre_questions_question = []

for row in pre_questions_file:
    pre_questions_question.append(row)

device_type = input(pre_questions_question[1][0])
device_type.lower()

if ('phone') in device_type:
    make = input(pre_questions_question[2][0])
    make.lower()

elif ('iphone')in make:
    model_iphone = input(samsung_question[1][0])
    model_iphone.lower()

elif ('samsung') in make:
    model_samsung = input(samsung_question[1][0])
    model_samsung.lower()

elif ('other') in make:
    make_other = input(other_question[0][0])
    make_other.lower()

    model_other = input(other_question[1][0])
    model_other.lower()

    problem_other = input(other_question[2][0])
    problem_other.lower

    info = print(other_question[3][0])

#other 
    text_file = open('Otherdevice.txt', 'w' )

    text_file.write(make_other)

    text_file.write(model_other)

    text_file.write(problem_other)

    text_file.close()

#apple

if ('4') in model_iphone:
    ios = input(apple_question[3][0])

elif ('5') in model_iphone:
    ios = input(apple_question[3][0])

elif ('5c') in model_iphone:
    ios = input(apple_question[3][0])


if ('7') in ios:
    memory = input(apple_question[4][0])

elif ('8') in ios:
    memory = input(apple_question[4][0])

elif ('9') in ios:
    memory = input(apple_question[4][0])

else:
    print("Sorry but you have entered invalid or not surported information please try again")


if ('8gb') in memory:
    query = input(apple_question[5][0])

elif ('16gb') in memory:
    query = input(apple_question[5][0])

elif ('32gb') in memory:
    query = input(apple_question[5][0])

#samsung

if ('s4') in model_samsung:
    android = input(samsung_question[2][0])

elif ('s5') in model_samsung:
    android = input(samsung_question[2][0])

elif ('s6') in model_samsung:
    android = input(samsung_question[2][0])



else:
    print("Sorry but you have entered invalid or not surported information please try again")


if ('jellybean') in android:
    service_provider = input(samsung_question[3][0])

elif ('lollipop') in android:
    service_provider= input(samsung_question[3][0])

elif ('marshmallow') in android:
     service_provider = input(samsung_question[3][0])
```

Comment: Format your code properly, give a minimal (non-) working example, post the full stack trace from that example.

Comment: So what is the value of `model_iphone` if `make` does not contain `"iphone"`?

Comment: There are a many issues with this code. Perhaps you should try writing a smaller, simpler script and testing it before building something like this. Your specific issue seems to be that 'iphone' isn't in make. Even if you correct that, you'll eventually run into "model_samsung" is not defined, because model_iphone and model_samsung are declared in mutually exclusive elif blocks, but they are both used in subsequent if statements. Try using a variable just named model...I take it that a single device can't have more than one model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kind of hard to follow what's going on in your code, but from what I can see, it looks like you're never making the variable `model_iphone`. Instead it seems like, since you're inputting "samsung", the code is making a variable called `model_samsung`, which does the same thing. Instead of making all these different variables that do the same thing (and only ever initializing one of them), try just making one uniform variable:

```
#Previous code...

#check for device type
if ('phone') in device_type:
    make = input(pre_questions_question[2][0])
    make.lower()

#separate if statement block to process the make and model after determining the type
if ('iphone')in make: #I CHANGED THIS LINE AS WELL TO WHAT YOU INTENDED IT TO DO (I think)
    model = input(samsung_question[1][0])
    model.lower()

elif ('samsung') in make:
    model = input(samsung_question[1][0])
    model.lower()

elif ('other') in make:
    make_other = input(other_question[0][0])
    make_other.lower()

    model = input(other_question[1][0])
    model.lower()

    problem_other = input(other_question[2][0])
    problem_other.lower

    info = print(other_question[3][0])

#other 
    text_file = open('Otherdevice.txt', 'w' )

    text_file.write(make_other)

    text_file.write(model)

    text_file.write(problem_other)

    text_file.close()

#apple

#ask the corresponding questions
if ('4') in model: 
    ios = input(apple_question[3][0])

#Continue code...
```

Note how all the inputs to the same question now all channel into the same variable, so that no matter what part of the if block is called, it will always initialize the variable you need, so that you can process later (I used `model` in the example).

It's also important to note that in an `if` block, if one part of the `if` block is used (the first one found when reading down), then all the other `elif` statements afterwords are ignored as well. If you want two *unrelated* `if` statements, you'd create the following code:

```
if statement1:
    #code here
elif statement2:
    #code not executed if statement1 is true

if statement3:
    #code executed, regardless of whether or not
    #either of the above statements are true or not
```

In this example, statements 1 and 2 are part of one `if` block, while statement 3 is part of another block. That might help fix some problems in your code as well. Good luck on coding, and keep at it!

Comment: thanks bspymaster yeah i see what i have done wrong now i just didnt see the error in my code thanks a lot i haveve been sat here for hours trying to find out whats wrong!!